# Converting a byte[] string back to byte[] array

Tags: c#, binary-data

I have one scenario with class like this.

```
Class Document
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public byte[] Contents {get;set;}
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the import export functionality where I keep the document in binary so the document will be in json file with other fields and the document will be something in this format.

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCitGbRsgEAALEHAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAA==
```

Now when I upload this file back, I get this file as a string and I get the same data but when I try to convert this in binary bytes[] the file become corrupt.

How can I achieve this ?

I use something like this to convert

```
var ss = sr.ReadToEnd();

 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

 writer.Write(ss);
 writer.Flush();
 stream.Position = 0;  

 var bytes = default(byte[]);

 bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: How is the string encoded? I've had issues similar to this, and I had to decode the string to get the correct byte[]

Comment: I don't think I added any encoding for the file. Its simple returned from binary column of DB

Comment: Your string seems to be a base64-encoded ZIP file. You need to know in exactly what format it is before you can do anything.

Comment: As an aside OP, make sure you're disposing your objects where necessary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - no you don't. If it looks like Base64 then you can use `FromBase64String()` as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to de-code it from `base64`, like this:

Assuming you've read the file into `ss` as a string.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ss);
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like base 64. Use:

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(b)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String(s)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are several things going on here.  You need to know the encoding for the default `StreamWriter`, if it is not specified it defaults to `UTF-8` encoding.  However, .NET strings are always either `UNICODE` or `UTF-16`.

[MemoryStream from string - confusion about Encoding to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188131/memorystream-from-string-confusion-about-encoding-to-use)

I would suggest using `System.Convert.ToBase64String(someByteArray)` and its counterpart `System.Convert.FromBase64String(someString)` to handle this for you.